# React + Express With Passport.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am setting up a full-stack application using React and Express JS.

I'm using Passport.js for authentication and have come across a slight problem...

So my front-end and back-end are two separate packages running on two different ports. On my express app, I have created a route like the following.

```
app.post('/api/account/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
      successRedirect: '/dashboard',
      failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    }) (req, res, next);
  });
```

This is pretty standard as far as Passport.js goes. Basically, if it authenticates the credentials I have provided, then it should redirect me to /dashboard. If not, then to the other mentioned route.

I am able to call reach this endpoint from my react application and get the correct response like the following in the network tab of chrome.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/dashboard
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

However, it doesn't actually redirect me to /dashboard. Is it not possible to do it this way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your React app is calling the route via ajax using something like `fetch`.

The way you're using Passport assumes that a browser is issuing the requests directly. On a successful login, Passport returns a Redirect response (HTTP 302 or similar), which the browser honors and redirects the user to.

Ajax requests don't work this way, *since there isn't any navigation happening*.

You'll need to handle this yourself on the React side of things. Your Express app will need to handle the session authentication by (for instance) returning a JSON message with a token or storing a session cookie. You'll need to update your React app to recognize this and then navigate to the correct route via client-side Javascript.

If you're using `react-router`, they have some [sample code](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) that might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I am using fetch. Hmm, doesn't passport.js create a session cookie? So you are saying to reach the /login API endpoint, and have that respond either "authenticated" or "not-authenticated" and read that message in the React app? Then redirect based on that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I recently did something eerily similar, but using Vue instead of React. I simply returned a `json` result that looked something like `{ authenticated: true }`, then used `vue-router` to navigate to the desired page afterwards.

Comment: Something to keep in mind for the near future: the session cookie will not get set properly on cross origin `fetch` requests. I recommend running your two apps on the same local port. I used the [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) setting in webpack-dev-server to make my server appear to run on the same port as my front end. See the [fetch docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Differences_from_jQuery) for more info.

Comment: Is that a viable solution even for production though?

Comment: Yes. Ideally in production your Express app will serve your static files as well or that they at least run on the same domain. During development, it's a little tougher to integrate because we have such great tooling that e.g. auto-refreshes the page on change. Simply proxying the server requests to the same port as the client is the simplest "fix" I was able to come up with to solve the CORS cookie issue during development.

Comment: When you say proxying, do you mean this?   "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
I put this in my package.json where my react code lies. This way all of my API requests go through there.

Comment: Can't I do it this way and then when in production, just do npm run build and use the static files instead?